# trigger lambda function from DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Every time a new item arrives in my dynamo table, I want to run a lambda function `trigger_lambda_function`. This is how I define my table and trigger. However, the trigger does not work as expected.

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "filenames" {
  name           = local.dynamodb_table_filenames
  billing_mode   = "PROVISIONED"
  read_capacity  = 1000
  write_capacity = 1000
  hash_key       = "filename"

  #range_key      = ""

  attribute {
    name = "filename"
    type = "S"
  }

  tags = var.tags
}


resource "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping" "allow_dynamodb_table_to_trigger_lambda" {
  event_source_arn  = aws_dynamodb_table.filenames.stream_arn
  function_name     = aws_lambda_function.trigger_stepfunction_lambda.arn
  starting_position = "LATEST"
}
```

Upon `terraform apply`, I get an error that:

```
│ Error: error creating Lambda Event Source Mapping (): InvalidParameterValueException: Unrecognized event source.
│ {
│   RespMetadata: {
│     StatusCode: 400,
│     RequestID: "5ae68da6-3f6d-4adb-b104-72ae584dbca7"
│   },
│   Message_: "Unrecognized event source.",
│   Type: "User"
│ }
│ 
│   with module.ingest_system["alpegatm"].aws_lambda_event_source_mapping.allow_dynamodb_table_to_trigger_lambda,
│   on ../../modules/ingest_system/dynamo.tf line 39, in resource "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping" "allow_dynamodb_table_to_trigger_lambda":
│   39: resource "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping" "allow_dynamodb_table_to_trigger_lambda" {
```

I also tried `.arn` instead of `stream_arn`but that threw an error too. What else could I try?

I followed the documentation for the trigger:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_event_source_mapping

Comment: A random guess - despite the error message text, could it be lack of IAM permissions for your Lambda to call `dynamodb:*`?

Comment: the role assigned has ```"dynamodb:GetItem","dynamodb:PutItem",  "dynamodb:UpdateItem", "dynamodb:Query"```but I doubt that's the problem@GrzegorzOledzki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`aws_dynamodb_table`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/dynamodb_table#stream_enabled) docs, `stream_arn` is only available if `stream_enabled` is set to `true`. You might want to add `stream_enabled = true` to your DynamoDB table definition.

By default `stream_enabled` is set to `false`. You can see all the default values [here](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/dynamodb-table/aws/latest) for `aws_dynamodb_table`.

Comment: then it would also require me to give a stream_view_type. what would that be? "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"?

Comment: It depends what you want your stream to contain: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_StreamSpecification.html. `NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES` will have both versions of an item if is modified.